# Select from dropdown box - selenium

Tags: selenium

HTML:

```
<span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-27--value">
  <div class="Select-placeholder">Select</div>
  <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
    <style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style>
    <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-27--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Code:

```
Select role = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='react- 
select-17--value']/div")));
role.selectByVisibleText("Manager");
```

also tried:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='react-select-27--value']/div[1]");
By.xpath("//*[@id='react-select-27--value']");
```

I am getting following error.

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='react-select-17--value']/div"}
```

please help.

Comment: I don't see an element with id `react-select-17--value` in your code, did you mean `react-select-27--value`

Comment: You can apply `Select` to `select` nodes only, but not to `span` nodes

Comment: Have you tried finding the element alone, without the Select, I have a feeling Select won't be compatible with your sourcecode here as it's based on working for Select and Option elements, and in this case you are trying to make it work on spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use Select. bec it's only applicable to select tag only.

In your case you have **input** tag with **combobox role** . Please try below code

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@role='combobox' and @aria-activedescendant='react-select-27--value']");

ele.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Manager')");
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='Select-multi-value-wrapper']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Manager')").click();

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown you are targeting is not your conventional HTML `<select>` element, hence `Select` class won't work. Instead you should do something like this -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='Select-multi-value-wrapper']")).click();
```

No you need to locate the exact option. Normally, you cannot see all your React elements inside your inspector. If you are using Chrome browser, you can install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) extension and then view your elements, locate them and click on it using Selenium through your regular locators.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you can not use `Select` here because it is a bootstrap drop down so that you can use like below sample code

```
WebElement DropDownClick = driver.findElement("Locator Value");
DropDownClick.click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //List of Drop Down locator
    List<WebElement> Drop_options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='Select-multi-value-wrapper']//div"));
    for (WebElement temp: Drop_options ) {
        if (temp.getText().contains("Manager") {
            temp.click();
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Continue");
        }
```

Comment: dropdwon list finds the size, but not selecting "Manager", going to else loop.

Comment: Are element is in this div : <div class="Select-placeholder">Select</div>